# Proof of Lebesgue measurable functions

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I am doing some independent study over measure theory. I am using the textbook written by Stein. However, I have one question about the proof of measurable functions.

> If $f$ and $g$ are measurable, then
>
> (i). The integer powers $f^k$, $k \geq 1$ are measurable
>
> (ii). $f+g$ and $fg$ are measurable if and only if both $f$ and $g$ are finite-valued.

I don't understand the proof of (ii) as the author goes

> We first see that $f+g$ is measurable because
>
> $\{f+g>a\} = \cup_{r \in \mathbb{Q}}\{f>a-r\}\cap \{g>r\}$ with $\mathbb{Q}$ denoting rationals.

Would someone explain why it holds for all rationals and how it relates to the condition of finite-valued functions? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What if at some point $f(x) = -\infty, g(x) = \infty$?

Comment: (Assuming $f$ and $g$ to be real-valued.) The idea is that for a given $x$, $f(x)+g(x)>a$ if and only if $g(x)>a-f(x)$ if and only if there exists a rational number (call it $r$) with $a-f(x)<r<g(x)$.